# Alternatives to FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server

We have a query that looks for discrepancies between two tables in two different databases (one SQL Server, one Oracle) that in theory should always be in sync. The query pulls the data from both tables into table variables and then does a FULL OUTER JOIN to find the discrepancies. We suspect that the FULL OUT JOIN is partially to blame for the performance issues.

Would it make sense to rely on two LEFT OUTER JOINs and look for records that don't exist on the right side of the join?

We're also thinking about using temp tables to further help with performance.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to offer any solid advice here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try temporary tables instead of table variables, that might help. Also, put relevant indexes on those temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the EXCEPT operator which handles complex joins, and it should work in both PL-SQL and T-SQL. It will return any values in the left table that are not a perfect match on the right table:

```
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3]
FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3]
FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3]
FROM Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3]
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I'm in a situation where the end result needs to include records that are in one table but not the other (all records in A not in B and all records in B not in A), hence the FULL OUTER JOIN. We're already inserting the results of the FOJ into a table variable. This is a part of a Table Valued Function. My thought was to break up the insert into two LEFT OUTER JOINS and handle the inserts separately to get all of the records.

Comment: You can use a UNION and flip it to get both results together. And I honestly don't know if this is faster than a FOJ: they may end up with the same execution plan in the end.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do a inner join and store results in a temp table. Then do a select from TableA where not exists in tempTableWithCommonRecords 
and another select from TableB where not exists in tempTableWithCommonRecords

Cant say if this will perform better as don't have enough info for that. Its just another option.